# Trouble with ThreadStateException when using Clipboard method

Tags: c#, clipboard

Hi I got this messege when debugging, and don't know how to find a solution.
System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Here is the code:

```
    namespace PhoneTaker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> NamesList = File.ReadLines("Names.txt").ToList();
            string str = NamesList.ElementAt(0);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetText(str);
            NamesList.Remove(str);
            File.WriteAllLines("Names.txt", NamesList);
            Console.WriteLine("All Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The clipboard requires an STA thread to support clipboard clients that are not thread-safe.  As long as you only put text on the clipboard that is not a real issue.  Put the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method.

Comment: @Hans Passant you mean something like that: STAThreadAttribute Stat

Comment: Just like I wrote it, copy/paste it from the comment to a line above Main.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for your help